# Unix shell script problem with space in the file name

Tags: shell, file, unix, space

> I an new to shell scripting. We have a requirement to write a shell
>   script for below requirement.  We will get daily files in the below
>   format.
>   1. /app/dstage/BAL/Activ Bal_pen_20200129.xls
>   2. /app/dstage/BAL/Activ Bal_pen_20200130.xls
>   3. /app/dstage/BAL/Activ Bal_pen_20200131.xls We need to write a shell script as soon as the files arrvies in the > direcotry I need move
>   them to another staging directory. I am writing below script. However
>   i am getting message file not found even the file "Activ
>   Bal_pen_20200129.xls" present in the directory. I am seeing the
>   problem is with the space in the file name. How to resolve the space
>   issue in the file name. my Script is below:

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Validation the number of arguments
if (( $# == 4 )); then
   Pattern=$1
   numFilesExpected=$2
   stgDir=$3
   maxWaitTime=$4
else
   print -u2 "Wrong number of arguments (${#}): Usage FileValidation.ksh <Pattern> <numFilesExpected> <stgDir> <maxWaitTime>"
   return 8
fi

# While max waiting duration is not obtained find files and set the array containing the file names; closing STDERR in case no files are found
waitTime=0

while (( $waitTime < $maxWaitTime )) ; do
        set -A fileList $(ls $Pattern 2<&-)

   if (( ${#fileList[@]} != 0 )); then
      break
   fi

   sleep 5
   ((waitTime++))
done

# Resetting the fileList in case it did not go in the loop
set -A fileList $(ls $Pattern 2<&-)

# Verifying if the pattern returned a file
if (( ${#fileList[@]} == 0 )); then
   print -u2 "No file found with pattern: $Pattern"
   return 1

#
elif [[ $(basename "$Pattern") = "*" ]]; then
   print -u2 "Found a source file pattern with no prefix (only a path with wildcard *): $Pattern"
   return 1

# Validation of the number of files expected
elif (( $numFilesExpected != 0 && ${#fileList[@]} != $numFilesExpected )); then
   print -n "${#fileList[@]}"
   return 2
fi
```

Comment: You might get a quicker response if you make your code readable. use code tags or backticks

Comment: code edited. can some one guide me

Comment: Try shellcheck.net

Comment: Create a [mcve] that isolates and demonstrates **just** the problem you would like help with and [edit] your question to replace your much larger script with that. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: I have the below files in the directory:

Comment: What's your method?  Do you intend to poll the directory?  Do you want to use inotify or fswatch or some other notification mechanism?  What exactly is the question?

Comment: The problem is in this line: `set -A fileList $(ls $Pattern 2<&-)`. Word-splitting doesn't distinguish between spaces *in* a file name and spaces *between* file names.